# get latest record date for each user using linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I had a similar situation as the OP here: [how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

The accepted answer worked for me, but now I need to implement the same thing in Linq to SQL in ASP.NET. How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

you can use it as follows

```
from t in Users
join tm in Users
on t.UserName equals tm.UserName
where t.Date == (Users.Where(a=>a.UserName == t.UserName).Select(b=>b.Date)).Max()
group t by new
   {
       t.UserName,
       t.Date,
       t.Value
    } into g   
select new 
    {
      g.Key.UserName,
      g.Key.Date,
      g.Key.Value
     }
```