# Sql Query help is needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write a query and optimize it's performance as well but not sure how to write it correctly. Here is the table structure.

```
"Subject Id"
"Class"
"Student"
"Marks"
"Date"
```

Date is when the record for the student was added. This table is denormalized. So I wanted to know how I can get the list of student, their class and their latest marks(i.e. the marks that were added the last) for a given subject Id from this table such that the rows are not repeated . Can anyone suggest this query?

Comment: The latest marks for each class or the latest marks period?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the title more meaningful. As it is now, it gives no information that will be useful to future users of this site who are searching for help. Please remember when posting here that your question should be helpful to future readers here, and it needs to be written with that in mind. Questions that aren't typically don't last long here. (It also helps keep it open when you actually show some effort to solve the problem yourself. What have you tried to do to write the SQL yourself to solve this? Please add that while you're editing as well). Thanks.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should at least partially accomplish that:

```
SELECT t.Student, t.Class, t.Marks
FROM tableName t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Student, max(Date) as MaxDate
    FROM tableName)
tm ON t.Student=tm.Student AND t.Date=tm.MaDate)
WHERE "Subject ID"=givenSubjectID
```

Answer adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user).