# Get latest sql rows based on latest date and per user

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
RowId, UserId, Date
1, 1, 1/1/01
2, 1, 2/1/01
3, 2, 5/1/01
4, 1, 3/1/01
5, 2, 9/1/01
```

I want to get the latest records based on date and per `UserId` but as a part of the following query (due to a reason I cannot change this query as this is auto generated by a tool but I can write pass any thing starting with AND...):

```
SELECT RowId, UserId, Date
FROM MyTable
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ( 

// everything which needs to be done goes here . . .

)
```

I have tried [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411690/1158845), but get an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

EDIT: Database is Sql Server 2008

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: _per UserID_ means that you want to group by `UserID`. How do you want to group with a `Where` clause only?

Comment: Database is sql server 2008, yes i want to group by user_id, can be done in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT RowId, UserId, Date
FROM MyTable
WHERE 1 = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM MyTable AS t
  WHERE t.UserId = MyTable.UserId
    AND t.Date > MyTable.Date
)
;
```

Note that if a user has more than one row with the same latest `Date` value, the query will return all such entries. If necessary, you can modify the subquery's condition slightly to make sure only one row is returned:

```
  WHERE t.UserId = MyTable.UserId
    AND (t.Date > MyTable.Date
      OR t.Date = MyTable.Date AND t.RowId > MyTable.RowId
    )
```

With the above condition, if two or more rows with the same `Date` exist for the same user, the one with the greater `RowId` value will be returned.

Comment: I like this, short and readable. +1 However, if there are multiple records with a max-date for one `UserID` and OP wants only one row...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That is a good point, thanks. I'll add a note on that and a workaround.

Comment: Or in subquery we can use `TOP 1` with order by `Date` in `DESC` order, so in that case will get the latest record by date.

Comment: @Umair: I am not sure I understand what subquery you are talking about but if you mean the one used in my answer, it would certainly *not* work that way. `TOP n`, whether with or without `ORDER BY`, would not affect the results of an EXISTS subquery in any way.

Comment: I was thinking to add in `SELECT * FROM MyTable AS t WHERE t.UserId = MyTable.UserId AND t.Date > MyTable.Date`, but yes the where query you mentioned does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT RowId, UserId, Date
FROM MyTable
WHERE 1 = 1
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM (SELECT UserId, MAX(Date) MaxDate
       FROM MyTable
       GROUP BY UserId) m
 WHERE m.UserId = MyTable.UserId and m.MaxDate = MyTable.Date)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c3a4/1).

Comment: If there are multiple records with a max-date for one `UserID` and OP wants only one row, how could you modify this query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84b97/1/0

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The user said "I want to get the latest records" - note the use of the plural; I understand this to mean that if there are multiple records for the latest date for the same user, then OP wants all of them. Of course, I could be wrong, in which case I would need to know whether `RowId`, or some other column, could be used to determine which is the latest; if so, I would remove the grouping, add `RowId` to the inner query and change the `MAX(Date)` to be a windowed `rownumber`, then change the EXISTS join to be on `rownumber`=1 and on `RowID` - eg: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84b97/6

Comment: The plural would be correct also with one record per UserId. However, the row_number approach works fine. But i would remove the second order by RowId if it spent matter because you could replace it with Dense_Rank easily to get the  "multi-row" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the ability to modify anything within the `AND` clause you can do a query like this if you are using TSQL

```
SELECT RowId, UserId, [Date]
FROM @myTable
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ( 
    RowId IN (
            SELECT D.RowId
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT MAX(RowId) AS RowId, UserId, MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
                FROM @myTable
                GROUP BY UserId
        ) AS D
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  that `RowID` is an identity column:

```
SELECT t1.RowId, t1.UserId, t1.Date
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE 1 = 1
AND t1.RowID IN ( 

    SELECT TOP 1 t2.RowID 
    FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE  t1.UserId = t2.UserId
    AND    t2.Date = (SELECT MAX(t3.Date) FROM MyTable t3
                      WHERE t2.UserID = t3.UserId)

)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/163e0/4/0)</kbd>