# SQL query to find most recent date using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in a database. One called Users and one called Days.
The Users table has a column called ID which contains some numbers and an ActiveUser column which contains either a 0(not active) or 1(active).  The Days table has a column called UserID which contains the same numbers the ID column from the Users table has. It also has a column called Day which contains info like "2015-01-01 00:00:00:000".

Users Table:

```
ID   |   ActiveUser
-------------------
10   |   0
11   |   1
12   |   1
13   |   0
```

Days Table:

```
User_ID   |   Day
------------------
10        |   2010-06-24 00:00:00.000   
11        |   2011-07-05 00:00:00.000
12        |   2008-06-19 00:00:00.000
13        |   2010-06-20 00:00:00.000
10        |   2009-09-02 00:00:00.000
12        |   2010-08-15 00:00:00.000
11        |   2011-05-06 00:00:00.000
13        |   2012-04-25 00:00:00.000
```

I'm trying to create a query that finds the most recent Day listed for each Active user. So using the tables above, the query I'm trying to make should give me the following:

```
Day
------
2011-07-05 00:00:00.000
2010-08-15 00:00:00.000
```

Which corresponds to the two Active users with user ID's 11 and 12, both of which have two entries for Day, but the query picks the most recent date.

I'm new to SQL, and the closest I've got is below, which doesn't take into account the Users table (also, used https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411703/2480598 as a template):

```
select Days.Day
from Days
inner join (select User_ID, max(day) as MaxDay
   from Days
   group by User_ID
) tm on Days.User_ID = tm.User_ID and Days.Day = tm.MaxDay
```

This gives me the list of dates for users active and non-active.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server. Updated the tags to reflect this, sorry about that. Title was wrong as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is classic example where `APPLY` can be applied:

```
select * from users u
outer apply(select top 1 day from days where userid = u.id order by day desc)a
where u.ActiveUser = 1
```

If you want only the `day` column(I think it makes no sense):

```
select max(d) as day
from users u
join days d on d.userid = u.id
where u.ActiveUser = 1
group by u.id
```

Comment: This works, I'll have to look more into what apply does. The reason I just want the day column is for some code I have in C# just using the dates for certain tasks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select a.User_ID, max(a.day) as LatestDay from Days a
Inner Join Users b
on a.User_ID = b.ID and b.ActiveUser = 1
group by a.User_ID
```

The `inner join` limits it to active users only.  You can remove `a.User_ID` from the `select` if you only want a list of days.

Comment: Tried this. I keep getting an error saying "Invalid column name 'Day'" which certainly isn't an invalid column.

Comment: This shoud be `a.day`

Comment: Thanks @GiorgiNakeuri - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `join` to the users table to get the active users.  Here is a simple way:

```
select u.id, max(d.day) as MaxDay
from Days d join
     Users u
     on d.user_id = u.id
where u.ActiveUser = 1
group by u.User_ID;
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a syntax error near the "where" on line 6. I changed the names and all to match my tables but still the same problem.

Comment: @Gordon, has a little bug. Just place `where` clause before `order by` clause.