# how to select latest records from a table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

DB : Mysql

I am having a table (tblSomething) with following records:

[image]

Now i need to filter this records by selecting the latest unique records from this table.

result should be:

[image]

In 2nd image the joe and rina with 11/16/2015 is not available.

Can you tell me how to write a query to achieve this.

Comment: mysql or sql-server? can't be both.

Comment: @DarkKnight Actually, it _could_ be both, if we give a pure ANSI-92 query as an answer.  But yeah, he should label appropriately.

Comment: Why do the records `404 468 joe tina` appear twice in the result set?  Should the `11/16/2015` records not be getting filtered out by the query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because the uniqueness is based on ID1 and ID2 column with latest date row.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  There should only be _one_ `404 468 joe tina` record in the result set.  Why was the filter not applied here, but was applied for the `404 467 joe rina` record?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t1.Name1, t1.Name2, t1.date
FROM tblSomething t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM tblSomething
    GROUP BY ID1, ID2
) t2
ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND t1.ID2 = t2.ID2 AND t1.date = t2.date
```

The inner query determines, for each `ID1`/`ID2` pair, the most recent date.  Then a query on the entire `tlbSomething` table is restricted by retaining only those records which have this most recent date for each `ID1`/`ID2` pair.

Click the link below for a running demo using the sample data from the OP.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/408f1/2)

Comment: plus one for simple solution and explanation.

Comment: nice solution, what if it is having more fields, how will you handle this, see updated question.

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni Give the Fiddle a try.  The output matches what you showed us in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` or `str_to_date`

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE  str_to_date(t1.date,'%m/%d/%Y')=(SELECT MAX(str_to_date(t2.date,'%m/%d/%Y'))
              FROM table t2
              WHERE t1.ID2 = t2.ID2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 select t.username, t.date, t.value
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select username, max(date) as MaxDate
    from MyTable
    group by username
) tm on t.username = tm.username and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```

Reference : [how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tblSomething
(ID1 int, ID2 int, Name1 varchar(55), Name2 varchar(55), date1 date, cost int, days int, somefield int);

INSERT INTO #tblSomething
    (ID1, ID2, Name1, Name2, date1, cost, days, somefield)
VALUES
    (330, 435, 'sn1', 'hello1', '2015-11-17', 500, 12, 34),
    (404, 467, 'joe', 'rina',   '2015-11-23', 600, 23, 22),
    (404, 467, 'joe', 'rina',   '2015-11-16', 700, 11, 123),
    (404, 468, 'joe', 'tina',   '2015-11-23', 800, 23, 41),
    (404, 468, 'joe', 'tina',   '2015-11-16', 789, 11, 43);
```

try this

```
with res as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID1, ID2, Name1, Name2 order by ID1, ID2, Name1, Name2) as rn from #tblSomething)
    select ID1, ID2, Name1, Name2, date1, cost, days, somefield from res where rn=1
```

output

[image]