# How to write Entity Framework for the following SQL Server Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to write the following SQL Server query in Entity Framework but have been unsuccessful so far. Can someone please help with converting to Entity Framework syntax?

SQL table

```
username, date,      value
--------------------------
brad,     1/2/2010,  1.1
fred,     1/3/2010,  1.0
bob,      8/4/2009,  1.5
brad,     2/2/2010,  1.2
fred,     12/2/2009, 1.3
```

SQL Server Query

```
select t.username, t.date, t.value
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select username, max(date) as MaxDate
    from MyTable
    group by username
) tm on t.username = tm.username and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```

The original question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411703/1355975

Comment: Can you show us the query you wrote using Entity framework?

Comment: @PaulKaram if he would know an answer on your question - don't you think that he would ever posted a question here? :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database base class is DatabaseContext and you have a table named MyTable, you can select records from it this way:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext()) 
{ 
    var myTableRecords = context.MyTable.SqlQuery("your query goes in here").ToList(); 
}
```

You can run any RAW SQL this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what I'm looking for - I'll need to tailor it slightly but should provide me with what I need:

```
DateTime utcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

var result =
    entries // e.g. context.tableName
    .GroupBy(e => e.username)
    .Select(gr =>
        gr
        .Where(x => x.date < utcDate)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
        .FirstOrDefault()) // This will give us null for devices that
                           // don't have a status entry before the date
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToList();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757982/1355975