# Get first entry from an associated table Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a one to many relationship: User has many Payments. I am trying to find a query that gets the first payment of each user(using created_at from the payments table).

I have found a similar question with an SQL response, but I have no idea how to write it with Active Record.

[how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Quoting the answer:

```
select t.username, t.date, t.value
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select username, max(date) as MaxDate
    from MyTable
    group by username
) tm on t.username = tm.username and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```

For me, it would be min instead of max.

Thank you :)

Comment: what do you expect the result look like? All payments? or they have to come with their users as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for not replying to everything, but after multiple tests, this is the quickest answer (in run time) I came with:

```
Payment.where(:id => Payment.group(:user_id).pluck(:id))
```

I am saying it might not be the quickest way because I am using a sub query. I am getting the unique values and getting the ID's:

```
Payment.group(:user_id).pluck(:id)
```

Then I am matching those ID's.

The downside of this is that it won't work reversed, for getting the last payment.

There was also a possibility to use `group_by` and `map` but, since `map` is coming from ruby, it is taking much more time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for POSTGRES

```
Payment.select("DISTINCT ON(user_id) *").order("user_id, created_at ASC")
```

And For SQL

```
Payment.group(:user_id).having('created_at = MAX(created_at)')
```

Comment: I can't use a loop, I am trying to do everything in one query. Practically I need @user.payments.first for each user, from one query.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Hope it will serve your case

Comment: @FakhirShad for the SQL one, i think it should be `MIN(created_at)`

Comment: Yeah you can use min or max as per your requirement. Mix will provide you the first ever payment made and max will retrieve last payment

Answer (score 0):

If I'm going to answer the question above with: (I **don't based on given raw SQL**)

**User has many Payments. I am trying to find a query that gets the first payment of each user(using created_at from the payments table).**

```
Let say:
# Assumed to have a Single User, as reference
user = User.first

# Now, get first payment (from Payment model)
user.payments.last
# .last since it will always get the first created row by created_at.
```

If I fully understand what you're trying to do. I'm don't know why you need **max or min date**?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

If you want first payment of each user

```
dates = Payment.group(:user_id).minimum(:created_at).values
payments = Payment.where(created_at: dates)
```

From payment you can find user too.

I think you have username as foreign key, you can change accordingly. :)
Let me know if you face any issue, as I tested it works.

I know this answer is not the best, but it will work even or transactions with milliseconds difference, as rails saves date(created_at and updated_at) with ms level.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but try this :

In your controller :

```
  def Page
    @payments = Payment.first
  end
```

in your html.erb :

```
<% @payments.each do |payment| %>
  <p> <%= payment.amount %> </p>
```

Hope this help !

Comment: I am looking for a query, not a loop, as I said in the other question :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Record.association.order(:created_at).first
```