# Filter Records in SQL Table

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am quiet new to SQL and I have following data in the table.

[image]

And I need to get the below value from this.

[image]

Here I need to get the latest record from the table for each name, can anyone please help me on constructing the SQL query.

Regards
Anand

Comment: Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
Select * from table t
Where date =
    (Select max(date) from table
     Where name = t.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks Charles it helped me lot:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query also..

```
SELECT Name, marks, Date
FROM YourTable y
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Name, max(date) as MDate
            FROM YourTable y1
            GROUP BY Name
            ) y2 on y.Name = y2.Name and y.date = y.MDate
```