# How to get latest until date and everything from date in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Okay so I suck at SQL... 
If I have a table **Forecasts** in SQL Server (2015+) with columns **CityName**, **WeatherProviderName**, **TimeStamp**, **TempCelcius**, 
And what I want out of it is the forecasts for every *city* from every *weather provider* that has been reported in the last *2 days*, ***plus*** the latest forecast for every *City*+*Provider* that has not forecast anything in the last *2 days*.

Is there a single query to get this that is more performant that just requesting the 2 separately?
I know I can get the latest values (based off [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)) like this:

```
select t.CityName, t.WeatherProviderName, t.TimeStamp, t.TempCelcius from Forecasts t
  inner join (
    select CityName, WeatherProviderName, TempCelcius, max(TimeStamp) as maxTime 
    from Forecasts where TimeStamp < DATEADD(DAY,-2, GETDATE())
    group by CityName, WeatherProviderName
    ) tm on t.CityName = tm.CityName AND t.WeatherProviderName = tm.WeatherProviderName AND t.TimeStamp = tm.maxTime
```

(also tried with the partition from [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user), but it was more than 3 times slower for my test set)

I can get everything for the last 2 days with:

```
select CityName, WeatherProviderName, TimeStamp, TempCelcius from Forecasts where TimeStamp > DATEADD(DAY,-2, GETDATE())
```

but rather than running them both into 2 collections and combining, is there a way to get them both in a quick single query?

***Note on Answer***

I went with the union as suggested by @Forklift (thanks) in the comment below. It's the fastest of the options suggested. It looked like this:

```
SELECT t.CityName, t.WeatherProviderName, t.TimeStamp, t.TempCelcius FROM 
Forecasts t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CityName, WeatherProviderName, TempCelcius, max(TimeStamp) AS maxTime 
    FROM Forecasts WHERE TimeStamp < DATEADD(DAY,-2, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY CityName, WeatherProviderName
    ) tm ON t.CityName = tm.CityName AND t.WeatherProviderName = tm.WeatherProviderName AND t.TimeStamp = tm.maxTime
    UNION
    SELECT CityName, WeatherProviderName, TimeStamp, TempCelcius FROM Forecasts WHERE TimeStamp > DATEADD(DAY,-2, GETDATE())
```

I have also marked @SqlZsm as the answer because it does do it in a single query... so depending on your exact need you have either @Forklift or @SqlZsm to thank :)

Comment: You can use `UNION` to merge the two result sets if you're simply interested in making one call to SQL.

Comment: True; I suppose that does at least remove the round trip. Was hoping there might be something that didn't run the 2 iterations of the DB. Not hyper critical. As much for my education as my need.

Comment: I think the problem is that they are actually 2 different queries with similar shaped return data. I'm not sure how you would try to get those distinct data sets back by asking SQL only one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns all rows from the last two days, and the most recent row for those that do not have a row within the last two days using a subquery with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**:

```
select s.CityName, s.WeatherProviderName, s.TimeStamp, s.TempCelcius 
from (
  select t.CityName, t.WeatherProviderName, t.TimeStamp, t.TempCelcius 
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by t.CityName, t.WeatherProviderName
        order by t.TimeStamp desc
        )
  from Forecasts t
  ) as s
where s.TimeStamp > dateadd(day,-2, getdate())
  or rn = 1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YQS70477

test setup:

```
create table Forecasts (
    CityName varchar(32)
  , WeatherProviderName varchar(32)
  , TimeStamp datetime
  , TempCelcius float
)
insert into Forecasts values 
 ('Sierra Leon','CNN','19881230',30)
,('Sierra Leon','CNN','19881231',30)
,('Sierra Leon','BBC','19881231',30)
,('Sierra Leon','BBC',dateadd(day,-2, getdate()),28)
,('Sierra Leon','BBC',dateadd(day,-1, getdate()),29)
,('Sierra Leon','BBC',getdate(),30)
```

query:

```
select s.CityName, s.WeatherProviderName, s.TimeStamp, s.TempCelcius 
from (
  select t.CityName, t.WeatherProviderName, t.TimeStamp, t.TempCelcius 
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by t.CityName, t.WeatherProviderName
        order by t.TimeStamp desc
        )
  from Forecasts t
  ) as s
where s.TimeStamp > dateadd(day,-2, getdate())
  or rn = 1
```

returns:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|  CityName   | WeatherProviderName |      TimeStamp      | TempCelcius |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| Sierra Leon | BBC                 | 09.03.2017 19:49:06 |          30 |
| Sierra Leon | BBC                 | 08.03.2017 19:49:06 |          29 |
| Sierra Leon | CNN                 | 31.12.1988 00:00:00 |          30 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: No I am not after this. I am after the latest values only up to 2 days ago (see typo note below), then everything that has happened since then... For example if CNN have not put out a forecast for Sierra Leon since 1988 then I want that one... but I'll take all their NewYork forcasts for the last 2 days only.

Sorry typo on the first query... should have been -2 not -5. Doesn't make a huge difference other than confusion; but corrected now...

Comment: @Wizbit removed the `where` in the subquery that was based on that.

Comment: @SqlZsm this would give me the same as my first query with the < changed to a > wouldn't it? And as per comment in the post I found the partition a lot slower than the inner join

Comment: @Wizbit I added a demo, does that make more sense now? Ranking window functions (like `row_number() over()`) and aggregation window functions (like `max() over()`) can have different performance results. I would suggest you test it before saying it will be slower. -- the end result may be slower than the combined time of your previous individual queries, but if you were to `union` them, you will incur the cost of a `sort` operator to remove duplicates.

Comment: @SqlZsm. Neat; I missed the _OR_. So yep single query; but on the 400k row table I'm testing on it comes out slower than the union: Union = CPU time = 612 ms,  elapsed time = 79 ms; partition = CPU time = 1994 ms,  elapsed time = 187 ms. Still I think those are likely to be the best pair of answers...

Comment: @Wizbit If that's the case I would go with the `union`.

Comment: @SqlZsm to be honest teaching me of the existence of rextester.com is enough get the upvote... thanks for that and the education on better use of partition

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
select CityName, WeatherProviderName, TimeStamp, TempCelcius from Forecasts where TimeStamp > DATEADD(DAY,-2, GETDATE())
union all
select * from (
    select CityName, WeatherProviderName, TimeStamp, TempCelcius, row_number() over (partition by concat(CityName, WeatherProviderName) order by TimeStamp desc) as rn from Forecasts where TimeStamp < DATEADD(DAY,-2, GETDATE())
)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This is effectively the union approach mentioned by @Forklift with the partition approach to the latest value that I already mentioned in my original post; which I said was the same as the inner join, but slower by a factor of 3.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you are after then. Is this still an open issue then? If @SqlZim has the best answer, you should mark it as the answer.