# SQL Call Stored Procedure with array input

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

**Background**

[Piggybacking on a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217575/get-latest-data-from-sql-for/48226956#48226956) I have a table with these sample values:

```
Temp_Date             Building_ID          Sector_ID          Temperature    
[Date/Time]           [I32]                [I32]              [DBL]
1/9/2018 4:14:31 AM    456                   0                20.23    
1/9/2018 4:15:14 AM    123                   1                35.23    
1/9/2018 4:16:21 AM    123                   0                15.23    
1/9/2018 4:15:45 AM    123                   2                25.23    
1/9/2018 4:16:21 AM    456                   0                25.23    
1/9/2018 4:16:59 AM    123                   1                35.23
```

Currently, I am running this SQL query to get the latest value for each sector:

```
select 
    t.Building_ID, t.Sector_ID, t.Temperature, t.Temp_Date
from 
    MyTable t
inner join 
    (select 
         Building_ID, Sector_ID, max(date_time) as maxMaxTemp_Date
     from 
         MyTable t
     group by 
         Building_ID, Sector_ID) tm on t.Building_ID = tm.Building_ID 
                                    and t.Sector_ID = tm.Sector_ID 
                                    and t.Temp_Date = tm.MaxTemp_Date
order by
    t.Building_ID, t.Sector_ID
```

Learning more about SQL, I know that I can:

1. Add a `WHERE Building_ID = [I32 value]` to limit the values returned to one Building_ID value
2. Turn this into a stored procedure `show-temps` allowing my server to more efficiently return the desired filtered data with the statement `show-temps([value]).

Doing both of these would get me something that looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show-temps
    @Building int,
AS
    SELECT 
        t.Building_ID, t.Sector_ID, t.Temperature, t.Temp_Date
    FROM 
        MyTable t
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             Building_ID, Sector_ID, MAX(date_time) AS maxMaxTemp_Date
         FROM
             MyTable t
         GROUP BY 
             Building_ID, Sector_ID) tm ON t.Building_ID = tm.Building_ID 
                                        AND t.Sector_ID = tm.Sector_ID 
                                        AND t.Temp_Date = tm.MaxTemp_Date
    WHERE 
        (t.Building_ID = @Building)        
    ORDER BY 
        t.Building_ID, t.Sector_ID
```

**My question**: is there a way to pass an array of int values to the `WHERE()` function so that I could get the latest data for a set of buildings instead of calling the function multiple times?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause needs to be **after** the `INNER JOIN` (but before the `ORDER BY`)

Comment: Fixed, thank you. (note that the question still stands though)

Comment: What DBMS are you running? MS Access' [`PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861.aspx) params does not have an [array/list data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193793.aspx). This sounds like an SQL Server procedure. Please tag appropriately.