# Select latest record on many to many relationship

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have a many to many relationship like below. A user can change their role, and I want to get all users with their last role equals to role2 (example).

users

```
user_id | user_name  | user_password
1       | user1      | *hashed password*
2       | user2      | *hashed password*
3       | user3      | *hashed password*
```

roles

```
role_id | role_name | role_description
1       | role1     | *description*
2       | role2     | *description*
```

user_roles

```
user_roles_id | user_id | role_id | created_at
1             | 1       | 1       | 2018-04-10 01:01:01
2             | 2       | 2       | 2018-04-10 01:01:02
3             | 3       | 1       | 2018-04-10 01:01:03
4             | 1       | 2       | 2018-04-12 01:01:01
5             | 1       | 1       | 2018-04-13 01:01:02
6             | 2       | 1       | 2018-04-14 01:01:01
7             | 3       | 2       | 2018-04-14 01:01:02
8             | 2       | 2       | 2018-04-15 01:01:01
9             | 1       | 2       | 2018-04-15 01:01:02
10            | 1       | 1       | 2018-04-16 01:01:01
```

From those tables, I want to get things like

```
user_id | role_id
2       | 2
3       | 2
```

But all this time I got

```
user_id | role_id
1       | 2
2       | 2
3       | 2
```

`user1` should not be there because its last role was `role1`.
So what I'm trying to do is, get users where last role = 2.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**Addition**

The results that I wanted is all data from `users` table. So it might be like

```
user_id | user_name | <and all of the rest>
2       | user2     | ...
3       | user3     | ...
```

So that, the field `role_id` I mentioned above is just reference to select the user.

Comment: Why not just select the user like this: `SELECT user.user_id, role_id FROM users JOIN user_roles ON user.user_id = user_roles.user_id WHERE role_id = 2 GROUP BY user.user_id, role_id`

Comment: Well that works, but that query will include the `user1`, i want to select user with last role = 2, so this might include the `created_at` field. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, understood.

Comment: Maybe this can be of help? I know my databases, but suck at writing queries for some reason. This looks pretty much like what you need though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? `sql` is too generic.

Comment: Yes, mostly close to it, but it still get the `user1` even i've tried to put the criteria @Loek. I'm using mysql mariadb @PeterAbolins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution. Essentially, you are looking at each user's latest role, and only include it in the output, if the role is 2.

```
SELECT 
    ur.user_id, ur.role_id 
FROM 
    user_roles ur
WHERE 
    ur.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) 
                     FROM user_roles
                     WHERE user_id = ur.user_id)
    AND ur.role_id = 2
GROUP BY 
    ur.user_id, ur.role_id;
```

**EDIT**

Based on the additional information from the comments, the following will return all information from the Users table:

```
SELECT 
    u.* 
FROM
    users u INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ur.user_id
        FROM 
            user_roles ur
        WHERE 
            ur.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) 
                             FROM user_roles
                             WHERE user_id = ur.user_id)
            AND ur.role_id = 2
        GROUP BY 
            ur.user_id, ur.role_id) tmp ON tmp.user_id = u.user_id;
```

Comment: It works! But can I select all data from `users` table? So it might not be `select field1, field2 from user_roles` but mostly like `select * from users`

Comment: @Gregorio My edited version should answer that question.

Comment: @Gregorio If this solved your problem, perhaps you could mark it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using `where in` instead of `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subquery` with *correlation* approach and do the `joins`

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, u.user_password, 
       r.role_id, r.role_name,  r.role_description
from (select  t.user_id, (select role_id from user_roles 
                          where user_id = t.user_id
                          order by created_at desc LIMIT 1) as role_id
      from user_roles t
      group by t.user_id) tt
inner join users u on u.user_id  = tt.user_id
inner join roles r on r.role_id = tt.role_id 
where r.role_id <> 1;
```

Comment: It works too! But i need explanation, and also can I select all the data from `users`, not only from the subquery?

Comment: Thanks! I think it's though to translate this query to laravel (at least for me). I need to learn more about query builder.