# Need help in SQL query to get recently created job record with status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need distinct Jobid  with recent status

```
jobs table
------------------ 
JobId Status CreatedDate 
------------------
1     sent   4/24/2018  
1     draft  4/23/2018 
2     sent   4/22/2018
2     draft  4/21/2018
1     req    4/20/2018
```

I need result like this

```
---------------
JobId  Status
---------------
1       Sent
2       Sent
```

I tried this but giving duplicate jobids with different statuses records

```
select distinct JobId, Status, CreatedDate from Jobs order by CreatedDate desc
```

Comment: Would you at least mention which database you're using?

Comment: I am using SQL server database

Comment: @Diya Then add it to the tag!!!  Also what have you tried???

Comment: I tried this :select distinct JobId, Status, CreatedDate from Jobs order by CreatedDate desc

Comment: @Diya If you don't need `CretedDate` on the result, why would you include it in your query???  Remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select j.*
from jobs j
where j.CreatedDate = (select max(j2.CreatedDate) from jobs j2 where j2.jobid = j.jobid);
```

If you have an index on `jobs(jobid, CreatedDate)`, then this is probably the fastest option.

Comment: This could show duplicates if multiple results for a single job on same day.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT 
    JobId,
    Status
FROM
    jobs j,
    (
        SELECT JobId, max(CreatedDate) cd
        FROM jobs
        GROUP BY JobId
    ) as t
where j.jobid = t.jobid
and cd = j.CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using SQL Server version that supports [Common-Table-Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), I would use following query:

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY JobId ORDER BY CreatedDate desc) AS RN 
    from jobs)

select * from cte where RN = 1
```