# SQL Server : return most recent record based on date in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, inner-join

I'm having an issue with a pretty basic query, my temp table has a primary key and a column named `PropertyID1`.

I'm joining to another table that has 3 columns:

```
PropertyID, SalePrice, SaleDate
```

The query joins on `PropertyID1` and `PropertyID`, what I'm trying to get is the most recent iteration of the matching `PropertyID` as there can be 10+ matches per ID and I need the most recent only, with the column `SaleDate` being used to select the required records.

So the initial query is

```
CREATE TABLE ##RPP_CHECK
(
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     PropertyID1 VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO ##IDCHECK
VALUES (41572498), (41484495), (41590235), (41611406)

SELECT 
    ID, ##IDCHECK.PropertyID1, PropertyID, SalePrice, SaleDate 
FROM 
    ##IDCHECK
LEFT JOIN 
    [ODS].[RS1] ON [ODS].[RS1].[PropertyID] = ##IDCHECK.PropertyID1 
ORDER BY 
    ID
```

Which returns

```
ID  PropertyID1 PropertyID  SalePrice   SaleDate
--------------------------------------------------
1   41572498    41572498    0.0      01-01-2011
1   41572498    41572498    0.0      01-01-2012
1   41572498    41572498    1000     01-01-2018
2   41484495    41484495    1200     01-02-2018
3   41590235    41590235    2000     01-03-2018
3   41590235    41590235    0.0      01-01-1999
4   41611406    41611406    5000     01-10-2018
```

What I need it to return is

```
ID  PropertyID1 PropertyID  SalePrice   SaleDate
------------------------------------------------
1   41572498    41572498    1000    01-01-2018
2   41484495    41484495    1200    01-02-2018
3   41590235    41590235    2000    01-03-2018
4   41611406    41611406    5000    01-10-2018
```

I tried looking at some of the answers posted here, but they don't quite seem to fit, I'm pretty sure this is either a `MAX(` issue, or grouping, but not 100% sure so happy for any tips you can offer.

Cheers

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. (I googled your title & tags.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APPLY` often has the best performance:

```
SELECT ic.*, r.*
FROM ##IDCHECK ic OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) r.*
      FROM [ODS].[RS1] r
      WHERE r.[PropertyID] = ic.PropertyID1     
      ORDER BY r.SaleDate DESC
     ) r;
```

Comment: This one solved it for me with the easiest application.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ID, PropertyID1, PropertyID, SalePrice, SaleDate
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, t1.PropertyID1, PropertyID, SalePrice, SaleDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyID ORDER BY SaleDate DESC) rn
    FROM IDCHECK t1
    LEFT JOIN [ODS].[RS1] t2
        ON t2.PropertyID = t1.PropertyID1
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This did seem to work somewhat, but it seems to be pulling older data from 2014, ill have another crack tomorrow when i'm back on deck - thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: Your sample data does not show anything from 2014, and I believe the logic in my query is correct.  You should fix your problem now.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Use MAX built in function and GROUPBY built in function in JOIN and achieve your 
  result  



BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #Test ( ID INT ,   PropertyID1 VARCHAR(100) ,  PropertyID 
    VARCHAR(100) ,  SalePrice DECIMAL(12,2) , SaleDate DATETIME )

INSERT INTO #Test ( ID  ,   PropertyID1  ,  PropertyID  ,  SalePrice  , SaleDate)
SELECT 1,'41572498','41572498',0.0,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-01-2011',103) UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'41572498','41572498',0.0,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-01-2012',103) UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'41572498','41572498',1000,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-01-2018',103) UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'41484495','41484495',1200,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-02-2018',103) UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'41590235','41590235',2000,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-03-2018',103) UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'41590235','41590235',0.0,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-01-1999',103) UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'41611406','41611406',5000,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-10-2018',103)

SELECT ID  ,  PropertyID1  ,  PropertyID  ,  SalePrice  , SaleDate
FROM #Test
JOIN
(
    SELECT PropertyID _PropertyID , PropertyID1 _PropertyID1 , MAX(SaleDate) 
    _SaleDate
   FROM #Test
   GROUP BY PropertyID,PropertyID1
) A ON _SaleDate = SaleDate

ROLLBACK  TRAN
```