# find records of latest date along with other corresponding values on certain condition in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called "history" with some sample data below:

```html
SITE_ID TARGET_PRIMARY_KEY TARGET_TABLE UPDATED_AT         USER_ID
1             1025test 4             2018/10/25 12:01 e4
1             1025test 4             2018/10/25 12:02 e1
1             1025test 4             2018/10/25 12:03 e2
1             1025test 4             2018/10/25 12:04 e3
1             aaa         4             2018/10/19 15:01 e1
5             aaa         7             2018/10/19 15:02 e2
1             aaa         4             2018/10/19 15:03 e3
1             aaa         4             2018/10/19 15:04 e4
1             aaa         4             2018/10/19 15:05 e5
1             aaa         4             2018/10/19 15:06 e6
```

What I want to achieve is:
For each unique combination of `"SITE_ID"` and `"TARGET_PRIMARY_KEY"`, pick up the record that has the greatest (latest) value of `"UPDATED_AT"`
and also make sure the corresponding `"USER_ID"` is correct.

Expecting result is:

```html
1 1025test 4 2018/10/25 12:04 e3
1 aaa         4 2018/10/19 15:06 e6
```

I have tried the following sql:

```html
    SELECT 
        hist.SITE_ID AS siteId,
        TARGET_PRIMARY_KEY AS skey,
        hist.TARGET_TABLE AS targetTable,
        MAX(UPDATED_AT) AS lastActionDate,
        hist.USER_ID
    FROM
        history AS hist
    WHERE
        hist.TARGET_TABLE = 4
            AND hist.SITE_ID = 1
    GROUP BY TARGET_PRIMARY_KEY
```

However, the `"USER_ID"` information seems not synced with the `"UPDATED_AT"`
I got:

```html
1 1025test 4 2018/10/25 12:04 e4
```

Can somebody please give me some advise? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select h.*
from history h
where h.updated_at = (select max(h2.updated_at)
                      from history h2
                      where h2.site_id = h.site_id and
                            h2.target_primary_key = h.target_primary_key
                     );
```

Comment: Thank you. Using Correlated subquery solved the issue!!

Comment: The same where should be included in outer select otherwise rows matched to other site/pk would be selected.

Comment: @fifonik
I don't think its necessary. Reason:
①  physically, h2 is not accessable from outer select.
②  the inner where conditions have already connected an outer select entry with its corresponding inner select entry.

Comment: If there are more than one record with the same updated_dt value returned from inner table it woud be included in results or outer table regardless site_id & target_primary_key values.