# How to get last added field from MySQL database JOIN

Tags: mysql

My database has two tables

```
MariaDB [testnotes]> describe contactstbl;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| phone | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

MariaDB [testnotes]> describe notestbl;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| notes     | blob     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dateadded | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want a query that will show the last notes in the notestbl table for the give ID

contactstbl has about 100ish records I want to show them all even without notes

```
MariaDB [testnotes]> select * from contactstbl;
+------+------+-------+--------+
| id   | name | phone | email  |
+------+------+-------+--------+
|    1 | fran | 12335 | gf@g.m |
|    2 | tony | 45355 | ck@g.m |
|    3 | samm | 46545 | fs@g.m |
+------+------+-------+--------+

MariaDB [testnotes]> select * from notestbl;
+------+------------------+---------------------+
| id   | notes            | dateadded           |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2 days ago notes | 2020-01-12 00:00:00 |
|    3 | 5 days ago notes | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 |
|    3 | 3 days ago notes | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 |
|    1 | 1 days ago notes | 2020-01-13 00:00:00 |
|    1 | 3 days ago notes | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried a couple different queries and just cannot seem to get it right.

```
SELECT c.id,c.name,c.email,n.id,n.dateadded,n.notes FROM contactstbl c left join notestbl n using(id) GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY n.dateadded ASC;
```

Which is very close.

```
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
| id   | name | email  | id   | dateadded           | notes            |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
|    2 | tony | ck@g.m | NULL | NULL                | NULL             |
|    3 | samm | fs@g.m |    3 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 5 days ago notes |
|    1 | fran | gf@g.m |    1 | 2020-01-12 00:00:00 | 2 days ago notes |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
```

What I want to see is:

```
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
| id   | name | email  | id   | dateadded           | notes            |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
|    2 | tony | ck@g.m | NULL | NULL                | NULL             |
|    3 | samm | fs@g.m |    3 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 | 3 days ago notes |
|    1 | fran | gf@g.m |    1 | 2020-01-13 00:00:00 | 1 days ago notes |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use subquery in SELECT clause:

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.email,
    (SELECT n.id FROM notestbl n WHERE n.id=c.id ORDER BY n.dateadded DESC LIMIT 1) nid,
    (SELECT n.dateadded FROM notestbl n WHERE n.id=c.id ORDER BY n.dateadded DESC LIMIT 1) ndateadded,
    (SELECT n.notes FROM notestbl n WHERE n.id=c.id ORDER BY n.dateadded DESC LIMIT 1) nnotes
FROM 
    contactstbl c 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY ndateadded ASC;
```

Result:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->     c.id,
    ->     c.name,
    ->     c.email,
    ->     (SELECT n.id FROM notestbl n WHERE n.id=c.id ORDER BY n.dateadded DESC LIMIT 1) nid,
    ->     (SELECT n.dateadded FROM notestbl n WHERE n.id=c.id ORDER BY n.dateadded DESC LIMIT 1) ndateadded,
    ->     (SELECT n.notes FROM notestbl n WHERE n.id=c.id ORDER BY n.dateadded DESC LIMIT 1) nnotes
    -> FROM
    ->     contactstbl c
    -> GROUP BY c.id
    -> ORDER BY ndateadded ASC;
+----+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | name | email  | nid  | ndateadded          | nnotes           |
+----+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
|  2 | tony | ck@g.m | NULL | NULL                | NULL             |
|  3 | sam  | fs@g.  |    3 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 | 3 days ago notes |
|  1 | fran | gf@g.m |    1 | 2020-01-13 00:00:00 | 1 days ago notes |
+----+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.ID,
       C.NAME,
       C.EMAIL,
       N1.ID,
       N1.DATEADDED,
       N1.NOTES
FROM CONTACTSTBL C
LEFT JOIN NOTESTBL N1 USING(ID)
LEFT JOIN NOTESTBL N2 ON N1.ID = N2.ID
AND N1.DATEADDED < N2.DATEADDED
WHERE N2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY N1.DATEADDED;
```

also try some ideas from here
[how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that you should change the schema of your `notestbl` table as it doesn't have its own id field, but instead relies purely on the id of the `contactstbl` table. This is bad design and should be normalised so as to prevent you pain in the future :)

I'd recommend it is changed to something like this:

```
mysql> select * from notestbl;
+------+------------+------------------+---------------------+
| id   | contact_id | notes            | dateadded           |
+------+------------+------------------+---------------------+
|    1 |          1 | 2 days ago notes | 2020-01-12 00:00:00 |
|    2 |          3 | 5 days ago notes | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 |
|    3 |          3 | 3 days ago notes | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 |
|    4 |          1 | 1 days ago notes | 2020-01-13 00:00:00 |
|    5 |          1 | 3 days ago notes | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 |
+------+------------+------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then you can use this single line query to get the result you're after:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.email, n.id, n.dateadded, n.notes from contactstbl c left join (select t1.id, t1.contact_id, t1.dateadded, t1.notes from notestbl t1, (select contact_id, max(dateadded) as maxdate from notestbl group by contact_id) t2 where t1.contact_id=t2.contact_id and t1.dateadded=t2.maxdate) n on c.id=n.contact_id;
```

```
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
| id   | name | email  | id   | dateadded           | notes            |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
|    1 | fran | gf@g.m |    4 | 2020-01-13 00:00:00 | 1 days ago notes |
|    2 | tony | ck@g.m | NULL | NULL                | NULL             |
|    3 | samm | fs@g.m |    3 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 | 3 days ago notes |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

A more visually pleasing representation of the query:

```
select  c.id, 
        c.name, 
        c.email, 
        n.id, 
        n.dateadded, 
        n.notes 
from contactstbl c 
left join   (select t1.id, 
                    t1.contact_id, 
                    t1.dateadded, 
                    t1.notes 
            from    notestbl t1, 
                    (select contact_id, max(dateadded) as maxdate from notestbl group by contact_id) t2 
            where   t1.contact_id=t2.contact_id 
                and t1.dateadded=t2.maxdate) n 
on c.id=n.contact_id;
```