# Select all entries that have the same Type as the entry with the largest Date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select all entries that have the same **Type** as the entry with the largest **Date**?

I'm using SQL Server.

My table:

```
+----+------+-------------------------+
| id | Type |          Date           |
+----+------+-------------------------+
|  1 | xxx  | 2020-02-25 09:11:53.000 |
|  2 | yyy  | 2020-02-25 08:30:35.000 |
|  3 | xxx  | 2020-02-25 07:48:17.000 |
|  4 | xxx  | 2020-02-25 09:04:25.000 |
|  5 | yyy  | 2020-02-25 07:59:03.000 |
```

The result should be:

```
+----+------+-------------------------+
| id | Type |          Date           |
+----+------+-------------------------+
|  1 | xxx  | 2020-02-25 09:11:53.000 |
|  3 | xxx  | 2020-02-25 07:48:17.000 |
|  4 | xxx  | 2020-02-25 09:04:25.000 |
+----+------+-------------------------+
```

Because id =1 is the Type with the max Date.

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: I play around with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user/2411763#2411763 but I didn't get it work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists` with *correlated* sub-query :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.type = t.type and t1.id <> t.id) and
      t.type = (select top (1) t1.type from table t1 order by t1.date desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery is often the most efficient method with the right index:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = (select top (1) t2.type
                from t t2
                order by t2.date desc
               );
```

The best indexes are `(date desc, type)` and `(type)`.

You can also do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(type) over (order by date desc) as last_type
      from t
     ) t
where type = last_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a Self Join, you could use `LAST_VALUE` in a CTE and then add that to the `WHERE`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.[Type],
           V.[Date],
           LAST_VALUE(V.Type) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LastType
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'xxx', CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2020-02-25 09:11:53.000')),
                 (2, 'yyy', CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2020-02-25 08:30:35.000')),
                 (3, 'xxx', CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2020-02-25 07:48:17.000')),
                 (4, 'xxx', CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2020-02-25 09:04:25.000')),
                 (5, 'yyy', CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2020-02-25 07:59:03.000'))) V (ID, [Type], [Date]))
SELECT CTE.ID,
       CTE.[Type],
       CTE.[Date]
FROM CTE
WHERE [Type] = LastType;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b0545497771492bd921d3776d884c39)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Declare @t table (id int , types nvarchar(100),dates datetime)

insert into @t values (1,'xxx','2020-02-25 09:11:53.000')
insert into @t values (2,'yyy','2020-02-25 08:30:35.000')
insert into @t values (3,'xxx','2020-02-25 07:48:17.000')
insert into @t values (4,'xxx','2020-02-25 09:04:25.000')
insert into @t values (5,'yyy','2020-02-25 07:59:03.000')


Declare @max nvarchar(100) = (select t.types from (
select top 1 max(dates) as t,types  from @t group by types
) t)

select * from @t 
where types = @max
```

**Output:**

```
id  types   dates
1   xxx 2020-02-25 09:11:53.000
3   xxx 2020-02-25 07:48:17.000
4   xxx 2020-02-25 09:04:25.000
```