# Find all records which contain certain string at the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with change history for orders

```
 cart_id     date                    action
 1           01/01/2020 3:00         approved
 1           01/01/2020 2:00         saved
 2           02/03/2020 9:00         saved
 2           02/03/2020 5:00         created
```

I need to get a list of all cart IDs where the latest action was "saved".  So in this case it would return only cart ID 2 because "saved" was the latest action, whereas the latest action of cart ID 1 was "approved".  I'm not really sure where to start here, any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Use `row_number()` to find the latest record for each cart, then filter on the action.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with `row_number()`, would this be in the where clause?

Comment: Please refer to documentation if you are not familiar with it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example:

```
select cart_id
from (
  select cart_id, action,
    row_number() over(partition by cart_id order by date desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1 and action = 'saved';
```

Comment: It is saying `Invalid column name 'action'`, assuming `t` is the table name

Comment: @JoeDefill I fixed it. Needed to add the columm `action` in the subquery.