# How do I get details of the latest transaction made by all customers?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Following is a sample table

```
SrNo, Date, TypeOfTran, CustID, AmtDue, AmtRec
1, 01-Jan-2021, 0,      A,       102,       0
2, 01-Jan-2021, 0,      A,       120,       0
1, 02-Jan-2021, 0,      D,       140,       0
1, 02-Jan-2021, 1,      D,         0,     176
2, 02-Jan-2021, 1,      D,         0,     188
1, 05-Jan-2021, 0,      P,         0,     196
2, 05-Jan-2021, 1,      L,         0,     134
```

*TypeOfTran [Due = 0, Receipt = 1]

SrNo resets on change of date and on change of TyepOTran

I want to create a query which would return last record of every customer.

A customer can make purchases and/or makes payment any number of time during the day.

I read the answers given in **[how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)** query but that is based on one condition that is date.

I am using MS Access

Thank you.

[Please see attached image of above table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peNiZ.png)

Comment: Define "last record of every customer".  Are you looking for the highest SrNo on the last date the customer did a transaction?  Given that you can have two series of SrNo's for each customer on each date, it would be hard to pick just one record for each customer.  You could get the highest SrNo for each type of transaction in a query pretty easily.

Comment: **"Are you looking for the highest SrNo on the last date the customer did a transaction?"** Yes, I am. Please advise. Order is like [latest] Date, [highest] TranType and highest [SrNo].

Answer (score 0):

You need another condition to match last `SrNo`. Try below query. Here `tDate` is your date column. As `date` is a reserve keyword, I used `tDate` as column name.

```
select t.*
from Table1 as t
inner join (
    select CustID, max(tdate) as MaxDate, max(SrNo) as MaxSr
    from Table1
    group by CustID
) as t2 on t.CustID = t2.CustID and t.tdate = t2.MaxDate and t.SrNo=t2.MaxSr
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Harun, Thank you for prompt reply, I did try what you have suggested but 'max(SrNo)' does not return the max(SrNo) relative to the max(TDate), instead it searches the entire database of the current 'CustID' and returns max(SrNo). e.g. if 'D' has done five transactions on 25-Feb-2021, then this query will return Max(Date) as 02-Jan-2021 and Max(SrNo) as 5

Comment: @Coder I assumed `SrNo` is based on each date. Means everyday `SrNo` starts from 1 and increase as much as records inserted. If that is not the case then how you will determine which record is last transaction for a customer for each day? Any other logic?

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So you need a second column to get the last one per day.  This would be solved if the date column had a time component, but that does not seem to be the case.  Let me assume that `SrNo` provides the ordering *within* a day.

If so:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) 
                from t as t2 
                where t2.custId = t.custId
               ) and
      t.SrNo = (select max(t2.SrNo) 
                from t as t2 
                where t2.custId = t.custId and t2.date = t.date
               ) ;
```

The first condition gets values on the last date.  The second gets the last value on the date, assuming that `SrNo` provides that ordering.

For performance, you want an index on `(custId, date, srNo)`.

Comment: Yes, SrNo does provide an ordering. Tried the query as you suggested but it did not return any result, waited for more than 15 minutes; still it is showing 'Running query' message in Status Bar below. Please note, I have many rows in the Access database.

Comment: @Coder . . . Try adding the recommended index.