# Select last Modified data record from the Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

[image: denter image description here]

This is the table what looks like. I want to select only the record that Last Modified Date is Max. EX: Will Only select 2nd record in above Table.
Is it possible?

Comment: This seems the same as your question. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a single row even if the max value appears more than once, use LIMIT:

```
select amount, created_date, last_mod_date
from the_table
order by last_mod_date desc
limit 1;
```

If you want multiple rows if the max value appears more than once, you can use a window function:

```
select amount, created_date, last_mod_date
from (
    select amount, created_date, last_mod_date, 
           dense_rank() over (order by last_mod_date desc) as rn
    from the_table
) t 
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

use order by and limit

```
select a.* from table_name a
order by last_mod_date desc
limit 1
```