# How to get the all unique value using foreign key in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a model `sensor` that stores environmental data from an Arduino(temperature, humidity).

```rb
create_table "sensors", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "system_id"
  t.float "value"
  t.datetime "created_at"
end
```

I want to get the average value by all my devices. To do it I need to get the last values from all devices by `system_id`.

The result I would like to get should look like this:

```rb
 [#<Sensor:0x0000556dd6a5c758
  id: 10,
  sensor_id: 1,
  value: 14.0,
  created_at: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 18:41:13 UTC +00:00,
 #<Sensor:0x0000556dd6a6f448
  id: 149,
  sensor_id: 2,
  value: 22.0,
  created_at: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 18:41:13 UTC +00:00,
 #<Sensor:0x0000556dd6a6f238
  id: 329,
  sensor_id: 3,
  value: 11.0,
  created_at: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 18:41:13 UTC +00:00,
  ...]
```

or just array of values corresponding to the task conditions:

```rb
[14.0, 22.0, 11.0]
```

I try it like this:

```rb
Sensor.order('created_at DESC').distinct(:system_id)
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `Sensor.select("system_id, max(created_at) as created_at").group(:system_id)`

Comment: @Eyeslandic thanks, yes, this is almost what I want, but as a result, there are no values that I need `[ #<Sensor:0x0000556dd86854e8 id: nil, service_id: 1, created_at: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 12:20:50 UTC +00:00>,  #<Sensor:0x0000556dd86854e8 id: nil, service_id: 2...]`

Answer (score 0):

You try this.

```
Sensor.order('created_at DESC').pluck(:system_id).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to get the latest records:

```
Sensor.joins('INNER JOIN (SELECT system_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_date FROM sensors GROUP BY system_id) latestSensor ON latestSensor.system_id = sensors.system_id AND latestSensor.created_at = sensors.created_at')
```

This might return multiple rows for a `system_id` if the `created_at` is exactly the same for those records.

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411703/4207394

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You will have to tweak this a bit probably to fit your situation exactly.

```rb
sensors = Sensor.select("system_id, max(created_at) as created_at").group(:system_id)

# To get values from this you can do something like
# This will give you an array like [[1, 2021-01-01], [2, 2021-01-01]]
sensors.to_a.pluck(:system_id, :created_at)
```