# After joining 3 datasets with a common identifier, how to only keep the rows with latest date but without missing the empty value rows?

Tags: append

SQL or R Solution needed (prefer SQL).

I have 3 datasets, all with a common identifier. After appending Table 2 and Table 3 to Table 1 using FROM

Table 1

| Common ID | District | Floor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | East | High |
| A002 | South | Low |
| A003 | West | Med |
| A004 | North | High |
| A005 | East | High |
| A006 | South | Low |
| A007 | West | Med |
| A008 | North | High |
| A009 | West | High |

Table 2

| Common ID | Last Enquiry Date |
| --- | --- |
| A001 | 31/01/2022 |
| A001 | 18/07/2022 |
| A002 | 20/05/2021 |
| A002 | 20/05/2020 |
| A002 | 20/05/2022 |
| A003 |  |
| A004 | 13/05/2022 |
| A005 | 18/08/2021 |
| A005 | 18/08/2020 |
| A006 |  |
| A007 |  |
| A008 | 27/01/2021 |
| A009 | 14/02/2020 |

Table 3

| Common ID | Last Completion Date |
| --- | --- |
| A001 |  |
| A002 | 29/11/2021 |
| A002 | 29/11/2020 |
| A002 | 20/05/2022 |
| A003 |  |
| A004 | 13/05/2022 |
| A005 | 22/08/2020 |
| A006 | 21/07/2019 |
| A007 | 24/04/2018 |
| A007 | 24/04/2019 |
| A007 | 24/04/2021 |
| A008 |  |
| A009 | 15/05/2021 |
| A009 | 15/12/2021 |

In SQL, tried the solution here but missed the empty rows. If I replace Inner Join with Full Outer Join, the max.date effect will be gone.

[how do I query sql for a latest record date for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411559/how-do-i-query-sql-for-a-latest-record-date-for-each-user)

Ideal output:
| Common ID | District  | Floor | Last Enquiry Date | Last Completion Date|
| --------  | --------  | ------| ---------------   | ---------------     |
| A001      | East      | High  | 18/07/2022        |                     |
| A002      | South     | Low   | 20/05/2022        | 29/11/2021          |
| A003      | West      | Med   |                   |                     |
| A004      | North     | High  | 13/05/2022        | 13/05/2022          |
| A005      | East      | High  | 18/08/2021        | 22/08/2020          |
| A006      | South     | Low   |                   | 21/07/2019          |
| A007      | West      | Med   |                   | 24/04/2021          |
| A008      | North     | High  | 27/01/2021        |                     |
| A009      | West      | High  | 14/02/2020        | 15/12/2021          |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, MAX(last_enquiry_date) AS max_last_enquiry_date, 
  MAX(last_completion_date) AS max_last_completion_date
  FROM table_1
  WHERE last_enquiry_date IS NOT NULL OR last_completion_date IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.last_enquiry_date = t2.max_last_enquiry_date AND t1.last_completion_date = t2.max_last_completion_date;
```

Assuming you have merged your tables, you first select everything from said table, you then create an inner join where you only select entries that have the latest dates and where both columns are not empty and group them by their id. Finally you filter your initial selection by only keeping entries that match the criteria of your inner join.
Note, if you use AND instead of OR, columns where either one is empty will not be selected, the AND statement returns 0 if at least one of the conditions returns 0, the OR statement only returns 0 if both conditions return 0.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your prompt response. I tried your solution but it will not include the row where last_enquiry_date  and/or last_completion_date is empty. I tried /*WHERE last_enquiry_date IS NOT NULL OR last_completion_date IS NOT NULL */ and use 2 OR to replace the 2 AND at the last part. But this would remove the effect of max date.

Comment: I would like the table to show for every id i have in Table 1, if it is empty in last_enquiry_date  and/or last_completion_date, just return empty;   if there is only 1 record in last_enquiry_date  and/or last_completion_date, just return that 1;  if there are multiple records in last_enquiry_date  and/or last_completion_date, return the latest date that record only